# dynamic_reconfigure exception when used with groups

Tags: ros, python, rqt-reconfigure, dynamic-reconfigure, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running

```
rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
```

And selecting my node, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/node_selector_widget.py", line 250, in _selection_changed_slot
    self._selection_selected(index_current, rosnode_name_selected)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/node_selector_widget.py", line 200, in _selection_selected
    item_widget = item_child.get_dynreconf_widget()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/treenode_qstditem.py", line 148, in get_dynreconf_widget
    self._param_name_raw)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/dynreconf_client_widget.py", line 57, in __init__
    group_desc, node_name)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py", line 153, in __init__
    self._create_node_widgets(config)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py", line 199, in _create_node_widgets
    widget = eval(_GROUP_TYPES[group['type']])(self.updater, group)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py", line 248, in __init__
    super(BoxGroup, self).__init__(updater, config)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

And indeed checking the python scripts, BoxGroup does call the super constructor with one argument too few. My config file looks something like this:

```
PACKAGE="my_package"
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *

gen = ParameterGenerator()

debug = gen.add_group("Debugging Utilities Left Image Based")
debug.add("dbgShowFeatures",                        bool_t,     0, "Show all detected features",            True) # online
debug.add("dbgShowNMSFilteredFeatures",             bool_t,     0, "Show stable (non maximum suppressed)",  True) # online
debug.add("dbgShowBest3kFeatures",                  bool_t,     0, "Show best 3000 features",               True) # online


exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "dynamic_reconfigure_node", "Foo"))
```

How can I fix this problem? I'm on ROS Groovy, 32 Bit Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86541/dynamic_reconfigure-exception-when-used-with-groups/) by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**UPDATE** [Grouping was added back in late 2014](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/pull/287).

---

Grouping in `rqt_reconfigure` is not yet implemented and [a ticket is already opened](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/162).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on 2013-10-07**:
Thanks Isaac, that is unfortunate, but good to know.